# Change Highcharts Graph based on two Select inputs

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, highcharts

I have an array of data of the following format:

```
[["sno","day","status","data1","data2","data3","data4"],
 ["1","01-12-2020","success","23","66","53","34"],
 ["2","02-12-2020","success","12","9","8","6"],
 ["3","03-12-2020","success","10","11","16","13"],
 ["4","04-12-2020","success","34","43","54","34"],
 ["5","01-12-2020","fail","45","26","36","44"],
 ["6","02-12-2020","fail","12","15","11","13"],
 ["7","03-12-2020","fail","34","43","33","29"],
 ["8","04-12-2020","fail","23","34","31","23"]
]
```

to display the particular text in Highcharts I used the Following code:

```
    var weekData = [["sno","day","status","data1","data2","data3","data4"],["1","01-12-2020","success","23","66","53","34"],["2","02-12-2020","success","12","9","8","6"],["3","03-12-2020","success","10","11","16","13"],["4","04-12-2020","success","34","43","54","34"],["5","01-12-2020","fail","45","26","36","44"],["6","02-12-2020","fail","12","15","11","13"],["7","03-12-2020","fail","34","43","33","29"],["8","04-12-2020","fail","23","34","31","23"]] ;

    //console.log(weekData);

    function change()
    {
        var valStatus = document.getElementById("statusSelect");
        status = valStatus.value;
        //console.log(status);
        
        if(status == 'success')
        {
            const successValues = weekData.filter((x)=>x[2] === "success"); //New Cases
            console.log(successValues);
            return successValues;
        }

        else if(status == 'fail')
        {
            const failValues = weekData.filter((x)=>x[2] === "fail"); //New Cases
            console.log(failValues)
            return failValues;
        }
    }

    function getCol(matrix, col){
       var column = [];
       for(var i=0; i<matrix.length; i++){
          column.push(matrix[i][col]);
       }
       return column;
    }

   function chartCreate()
   {
    change();

        const toNumbers = arr => arr.map(Number);
        var getstat= change();
        var day = getCol(getstat,1);
        console.log(day);
        var sdata1 = toNumbers(getCol(getstat,3));
        console.log("data 1" ,sdata1);
        var sdata2 = toNumbers(getCol(getstat,4));
        console.log(sdata2);
        var sdata3 = toNumbers(getCol(getstat,5));
        console.log(sdata3);
        var sdata4 = toNumbers(getCol(getstat,6));
        console.log(sdata4);
```

For the full program You can check my fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/abnitchauhan/L27n0wfs/

the problem is that when I am `status` select box, The Chart is not updating.

Also I feel that this code is quite lengthy when the datasets will increase overtime. is there any efficient approach to display this data on Highchart's based on the same select options.

Answer (score 0):

I made an update to JS code. See if this is what you want:

```
    var weekData = [["sno","day","status","data1","data2","data3","data4"],["1","01-12-2020","success","23","66","53","34"],["2","02-12-2020","success","12","9","8","6"],["3","03-12-2020","success","10","11","16","13"],["4","04-12-2020","success","34","43","54","34"],["5","01-12-2020","fail","45","26","36","44"],["6","02-12-2020","fail","12","15","11","13"],["7","03-12-2020","fail","34","43","33","29"],["8","04-12-2020","fail","23","34","31","23"]] ;

    //console.log(weekData);

    function change()
    {
        var valStatus = document.getElementById("statusSelect");
        status = valStatus.value;
        //console.log(status);
        
        if(status == 'success')
        {
            const successValues = weekData.filter((x)=>x[2] === "success"); //New Cases
            console.log(successValues);
            return chartCreate(successValues);
        }

        else if(status == 'fail')
        {
            const failValues = weekData.filter((x)=>x[2] === "fail"); //New Cases
            console.log(failValues)
            return chartCreate(failValues);
        }
    }

    function getCol(matrix, col){
       var column = [];
       for(var i=0; i<matrix.length; i++){
          column.push(matrix[i][col]);
       }
       return column;
    }

   function chartCreate(stat)
   {

        const toNumbers = arr => arr.map(Number);
        var getstat= stat;
        var day = getCol(getstat,1);
        console.log(day);
        var sdata1 = toNumbers(getCol(getstat,3));
        console.log("data 1" ,sdata1);
        var sdata2 = toNumbers(getCol(getstat,4));
        console.log(sdata2);
        var sdata3 = toNumbers(getCol(getstat,5));
        console.log(sdata3);
        var sdata4 = toNumbers(getCol(getstat,6));
        console.log(sdata4);

 var options = {
  chart:{
      renderTo: 'chart',
      defaultSeriesType: 'line'
  },

   title: {
        text: 'dummy'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: ' '
    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: ' ',
            //tickPointInterval: 250
        },
         minorTickInterval: 'auto',
        // tickInterval: 4,
    },

    xAxis: {
      
       labels :{
        minorTickInterval: 'auto',
        formatter: function(){   
         return day[this.value];
       }
       },
         
        tickInterval: 10
       
    },

    credits: {
     enabled: false
    },

    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            label: {
                connectorAllowed: false
            },
           // pointStart: 0
        }
    },

  tooltip: {
   // split: true,
    formatter: function() {
      var points = this.points,
        tooltipArray = ['day: <b>' + day[this.x] + '</b><br/> Value : <b>'+ this.y +'</b>']

      

      return tooltipArray;
    }
  },
  series: [
  {
    name: 'Check',
    data: sdata1
  }],

    responsive: {
        rules: [{
            condition: {
                maxWidth: 500
            },
            chartOptions: {
                legend: {
                    layout: 'horizontal',
                    align: 'center',
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                }
            }
        }]
    }
};
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

  $("#dataSelect").on('change', function(){
    //alert('f')
    var selVal = $("#dataSelect").val();
    if(selVal == 'data1' || selVal == '')
    {
        options.series = [{name: 'Data', data: sdata1}];
         options.yAxis = [{tickInterval:undefined,  minorTickInterval: 'auto'}];
    }
    else if(selVal == 'data2')
    {
        options.series = [{name: 'Data', data: sdata2}]
    }
    else if(selVal == 'data3')
    {
        options.series = [{name: 'Data', data: sdata3}];
         options.yAxis = [{tickInterval:undefined,  minorTickInterval: 'auto'}];

    } 

        else if(selVal == 'data4')
    {
        options.series = [{name: 'Data', data: sdata4}];
         options.yAxis = [{tickInterval:undefined,  minorTickInterval: 'auto'}];
    } 
     var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);    
});
}

change();
```

Comment: although . your code works good. I just don't think my code is that much optimal when the dataset increases. I need a logic for optimal code for larger data. I appreciate your help

Comment: If I am choosing the changing the status value in your code the `data1` of of first select box is displaying. rather than the current selected data

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks very complex and does not fully work. In this case, I will suggest using the series `setData` method mixed with the `change` event listener. My example is a bit simplified, but I think it might be the right way.

```
document.getElementById('dataSelect').addEventListener('change', () => {
  const selectorValue = document.getElementById('dataSelect').value

  chart.series[0].setData(data[selectorValue])
});
```

**API:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData
**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nfz0a9bm/

Comment: I understand working with one select box. I am working on a code that is having two select options, i think that is little complicated in my code.